# How to decode JSON in Go which returns multiple elements as array of type and individual elements as type

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, encoding-json-go

I am working with an API that sends JSON data. The problem is that an array of a single element shows up as a single value. For example, consider the following JSON:

```
{ "names": ["Alice","Bob"] }
```

The API sends this as an array. But when the `names` field has a single element, the API sends this:

```
{ "names": "Alice" }
```

This is how I would normally decode this of response in Go:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Names []string `json:"names"`
}

// later

d := &Response{}
_ = json.NewDecoder(resp).Decode(d) // resp would be a http.Response.Body containing the problematic JSON
```

Go decodes the first JSON correctly. However, after decoding the second JSON, the object contains an empty array.

I don't have any control over the API, so I have to get around this problem. How could I decode this JSON correctly in Go, so that the `Names` slice contains a single element? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface and have it check the 0th raw byte for `[` or `"` to find out whether it's an array or a string respectivelly:

```
type StringSlice []string

func (ss *StringSlice) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if data[0] == '[' {
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*[]string)(ss))
    } else if data[0] == '"' {
        var s string
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        *ss = append(*ss, s)
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/2GEJsS2YOLJ

Comment: Thanks, this worked best for me - it doesn't involve type assertions, which clutter up the code, especially with custom types (as in my case), and it doesn't involve other exported fields. Something I want to point out is that the first character in the raw data will vary, depending on the type. Instead of `"`, it is `{` for objects, for example. It might help others, seems straightforward now, but I overlooked this detail at first!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decode this into an `interface{}` and then use a type assertion to check whether the underlying type is a slice or just a string.

```
 type Response struct {
     Names interface{} `json:"names"` 
 }
```

Then after decoding into `d`, you'd do something like:

```
    slice, ok := d.Names.([]interface{})
    if ok {
      // it was a slice. use it.
    } else {
      // it wasn't a slice - so expect it to be a string
      // and use that, etc.
    }
```

Comment: Aren't arrays, if no concrete type is provided, decoded into `[]interface{}`, regardless of whether they are arrays of strings or not? i.e. would the `d.Names.([]string)` type assertion ever work?

Comment: @mkopriva: good point, thanks! I typed the code into SO without testing

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.RawMessage` as type. RawMessage simply delays the decoding of part of a message, so we can do it ourselves later.

```
type Response struct {
    NamesRaw json.RawMessage `json:"names"`
    Names []string
}
```

First, decode the response and then using `json.Unmarshal` decode `json.RawMessage`

```
x := &Response{}
_ = json.NewDecoder(resp).Decode(x);
x.Names = DecodeName(x.NamesRaw)
```

`DecodeName` used for decoding `NameRaw` data

```
func DecodeName(nameRaw json.RawMessage) (data []string) {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(nameRaw, &s); err == nil {
        v := []string{s}
        return v
    }
    var sn []string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(nameRaw, &sn); err == nil {
        return sn
    }
    return
}
```